# Kids horror TV series late 80's early 90's with two sisters named Cake and Cupcake

Tags: story-identification

There was a kids TV show either in the late 80's or early 90's where a group of kids/teens would look into supernatural events (I think). I really only remember that there were two sisters, the older one was called Cake and the little one Cupcake.

Does anyone know what this show was?

Comment: There was a time traveler named Cupcake on the animated Happy Days (1981) series.